# Как получить самую минимальную и максимальную дату из столбца таблицы содержашего недействительные значения?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь получить самую минимальную и самую максимальную дату из столбца таблицы. Использую следующий запрос в PL/SQL, из результата которого генерируется диапазон дат:

```
select 
    MIN(trunc(TO_DATE(MOD_BEGIN, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))) AS MIN_DATE, 
    MAX(trunc(TO_DATE(MOD_END, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))) AS MAX_DATE
from V_IPSL_PPE_MUC_AZEIT;
```

Но проблема в том, что столбцы `MOD_BEGIN`, `MOD_END` могут содержать недействительные значения (например: `0000000100000000`), из-за этого при выполнении запроса будет ошибка:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month

Нельзя изменять или удалять эти недействительные данные в таблице.

Как быть тогда в этом случае?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to get lowest and highest date from a table column in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65390904) от участника [@surajs89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12926082/surajs89)</sub>

Comment: ассоциаия:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65390904

Answer (score 2):

Если версися 12.2 или выше, это весьма подходящий случай для [`ON CONVERSION ERROR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html):

```
with t (mod_begin, mod_end) as (
    select '20200101200000','00000001000000' from dual union all
    select '20200102200000','20200103200000' from dual)
select 
    trunc (min (to_date (mod_begin default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as mindate,
    trunc (max (to_date (mod_end   default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as maxdate 
from t
/

MINDATE             MAXDATE            
------------------- -------------------
2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

Для недействительных значений `to_date()` вернёт `null` вместо ошибки, а агрегирующие функции игнорируют `null` значения.

---

Для более ранних версий будет полезна следующая функция вместо прямого вызова `to_date()`:

```
create or replace function convertdate (str varchar2, fmt varchar2) return date is
begin
    return to_date (str, fmt);
exception when others then 
    return null;
end convertdate;
/
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65390950) от участника [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) и [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65391147/6571020) от участника [@leftjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700344/leftjoin)</sub>